# How to type a single jamo using Dubeolsik keyboard?

Tags: typing

I use Dubeolsik with `ibus-hangul` with the Gnome desktop environment.

How can I type a single jamos? For example I don't want to type `머`, but I want to type `ㅁㅓ`.

Right now I am doing it by pressing the first jamo, then pressing any character that is not hangul (by that the jamo is committed as a syllable), then pressing backspace and then pressing the second jamo.

Is there a key or key combination which can be used instead to commit single jamos (and also commit incomplete syllables)?

Comment: I haven't tried typing Korean in Linux, but doesn't just pressing the arrow key work?

Comment: Splitting 한글 자소 - this happens occasionally when IME gets bugged. If only I knew how to reproduce that I would have answered this question... But in general just pressing right arrow key after typing each character is enough for most people since they rarely get to type single jamos.

Comment: @user17915 You answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: I found out that it is also possible to press Ctrl-Space to get the desired behavior.

Comment: on Ubuntu 22.04, pressing "ALT" or "ALT GR" also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help and input.

It seems, that pressing any key or key combination, that does not produce a single jamo works.

Here are a few examples:

- `Space` and then `Backspace`
- Any arrow key.
- `Ctrl` (my favorite, because of its postion)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write "ㅁㅓ". First you haveto write "ㅁ" fiirst. Then press the "space bar" and press "backspace" to erase space.
Then you have to write ㅓ.
That is the way how you can write ㅁㅓ.
I hope you undersand this.^^